# to sum dynamic columns with null values in pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

my code is :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.column_3) 
        FROM table_c c
        where Code = 123 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

exec('SELECT column_1, ' + @cols + ' from
        (
            select column_1
                , column_2
                , column_3
            From table_c where Code = 123 
        ) x 
        pivot 
        (
             sum(column_2)
            for column_3 in( ' + @cols + ' )
        ) p 
        '
        )
```

And i want to add only @cols columns and have result in a new column as total. These columns may have null values.

---

Let me Explain more :

in need a code that give me sth like this

```
@sum_cols = 'ISNULL([c.column_3_value_1],0) + ISNULL([c.column_3_value_2],0) + ... + ISNULL([c.column_3_value_N],0)'
```

as how I got

```
@cols = '[c.column_3_value_1],[c.column_3_value_1],...[c.column_3_value_N]'
```

In my above code.

(this 'c.column_3_value_...'s could have any chars and are not regular)

and use this @sum_cols in my exec query like this :

```
exec('SELECT column_1, ' + @cols + ' , ' + @sum_cols + ' As sum from
    (
        select column_1
            , column_2
            , column_3
        From table_c where Code = 123 
    ) x 
    pivot 
    (
         sum(column_2)
        for column_3 in( ' + @cols + ' )
    ) p 
    '
    )
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code is far from ANSI SQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean this?

I think you forgot the 'from' keyword before the first subquery after the exec...
The code you pasted won't run otherwise...

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.column_3) 
        FROM table_c c
        where Code = 123 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

exec('SELECT column_1, ' + @cols + '
        FROM 
        (
            select column_1
                , column_2
                , column_3
            From table_c where Code = 123 
        ) x 
        pivot 
        (
             sum(column_2)
            for column_3 in( ' + @cols + ' )
        ) p 
        '
        )
```

Comment: thank you. your right i corrected that but in my code it has 'from' keyword and it works correctly. I just want another column to sum each row for those @cols column that are unknown by name and the number of column.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want only values in `column_3` where the corresponding value in `column_2` has at least one non-NULL value.

You can arrange this using `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.column_3) 
                   FROM table_c c
                   WHERE Code = 123 
                   GROUP BY c.column_3
                   HAVING COUNT(column_2) > 0
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                         ), 1, 1, '');
```

The `HAVING` clause can be extended for other purposes -- such as ensuring a minimum count or guaranteeing that all columns have values.  But I think this is the version you want.

Comment: thanx for answering but it is not important for me that column_2 has values for my column_3 values as new columns in pivoted table. I just want to have the sum of @cols ([necolumn_1],[newcolumn_2],...) columns in pivoted table for each row in new column as total whether there are null values or not in each column.